# Azure B2C Page Customization - Use hypertext links instead of buttons for ClaimsProviderSelection

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I will like to replace ClaimProviderSelection buttons with just hypertext links. How can I go about this? I have taken a look a sample css (I am not a content developer) but it seems the part I am interested in is what B2C merges with between the `<div id="api"></div>` elements.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

B2C injects its HTML into the `<div id="api"></div>` element on the page layout template. Those buttons will all have the `accountButton` class so can be identified with the CSS selector `#api button.accountButton`.

If you're already using custom page templates then you should just be able to update your CSS to target those button elements and remove all of the default button styling, similar to this:

```
#api button.accountButton
{
    background: none;
    color: black;
    border: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

If you're not already using custom page layout templates then that should be your first step. There's guidance in [the Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-overview) about how to do that both if you're using user flows and custom policies.

Comment: Thanks @Dave! Will try this out and report back.